# Incrementing value in repeat loop unprecise (R code)?

Tags: r, loops, repeat

In R, the following script results in a strange but annoying "error":

```
delta_t <- 0.0001
t <- 0
maxtime <- 2

repeat{
  t <- t + delta_t
  print(t)     
  if(t==maxtime){
    break
  }
}
```

All the printed values actually show that the time is incremented by delta_t:

```
0
0.0001
0.0002
.
.
.
2
```

However, if you stop the run before the time reaches the maxtime, and you check your workspace for te value of t, you'll see something like this:
    t = 1.852200000000159

This also causes R not to break out of the repeat loop. I know that it is possible to replace the argument that is used in the if loop by:
    t>=maxtime

But I have a code where I really need an equal to in stead of a greater than.
Hope somebody can clarify this for me!
Thanks in advance, Robin

Comment: Yep, you're correct. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: There is no possible reason to "need 'equal' instead of 'greater than or equal" unless you are trying to hit an exact target. In which case the label `maxtime` is rather misleading.